# How to obtain the mean and standard deviation of 3 numbers that form an arithmetic sequence with the sum of 12 ($4$ and $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3})$?

Tags: arithmetic, descriptive-statistics

The sum of 3 numbers that form an arithmetic sequence is 12. Determine the mean and standard deviation. The answers are $4$ and $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$ respectively. 
*My attempt:*
$U_1=a-d$
$U_2=a$
$U_3=a+d$
$U_1+U_2+U_3 = 3a = 12$
$a=4$
$Mean = \frac{12}{3}=4$
$(U_1-Mean)^2 = d^2$
$(U_2-Mean)^2 = 0$
$(U_3-Mean)^2 = d^2$
$Total=2d^2$
$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{2d^2}{3}} = d\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}$

I can't obtain the difference $d$, which results in not obtaining $\sigma=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}.$

Comment: Indeed, without more information, the standard deviation cannot be obtained.

Comment: The problem seems to assume that $d = \sqrt 2$, which would give the arithmetic sequence by

$$U_1 = 4 - \sqrt 2 \qquad U_2 = 4 \qquad U_3 = 4 + \sqrt 2$$

It is trivial to show that the arithmetic mean is $4$, the sum is $12$, and the (population) standard deviation is $2 \sqrt 3/3$. However, clearly, tweaking $d$ doesn't change matters. For instance, using $d=0$ is an obvious case of mean being $4$, and the sum being $12$, but the standard deviation is $0$. More information is needed.